# Why I'm getting all history revisions when querying for Iterations or Releases?

Tags: rally

I'm working with Rally REST API for Java 
I want get the list of actual Iterations and Releases 
here is the snippet

```
JsonObject projects = new JsonObject();
    QueryRequest queryProjects = new QueryRequest("release");
    queryProjects.setPageSize(1);
    queryProjects.setLimit(1000);
    queryProjects.setFetch(new Fetch("_refObjectName","Name"));
    QueryResponse queryResponse;
    try {
        queryResponse = restApi.query(queryProjects);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        throw new ServiceException(e);
    }
```

In result I'm getting the list with a lot of duplicates. After closer inspection it seems I'm getting all versions of object - for the same Iteration/Release I have multiple versions - I can see different "_objectVersion" attribute for such duplicates.

Why is it so?

Can you please help me with the query which will retrieve distinct list of Iterations / Releases - I'm interested in just latest versions.

I can filter it out in Java but have a feeling there is more 'proper' way of doing this. Also getting the list with whole object history is not the best for code performance.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

When Releases and Iterations are created in Rally in a top project there is an option to propagate them throughout the project hierarchy. For example, if you have top project P1 with child project P2 and grandchild projects P21 and P22, you may create 4 releases with the same name and the same start and release dates. They are not identical releases: they have ObjectID and _ref unique to them. Please verify if this applies to your scenario.

To limit release query to a specific project set request project. Here is an example that returns only three releases that I have in a top project: R1,R2, and R3. Note

```
String projectRef = "/project/12352608219";
```

that is used later in the code:

```
releaseRequest.setProject(projectRef);
```

Note also the commented out

```
//String workspaceRef = "/workspace/12352608129";
```

and

```
// releaseRequest.setWorkspace(workspaceRef);
```

If I switch the comments: comment out project reference and uncomment workspace reference I will get what you called duplicates: multiple R1, R2 and R3 releases.

```
public class FindReleases {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {


        String host = "https://rally1.rallydev.com";
            String username = "user@co.com";
            String password = "secret";
            String projectRef = "/project/12352608219";
            //String workspaceRef = "/workspace/12352608129"; 
            String applicationName = "RESTExampleFindReleasesByProject";

            RallyRestApi restApi = null;

        try {
                restApi = new RallyRestApi(
                        new URI(host),
                        username,
                        password);
                restApi.setApplicationName(applicationName); 

                System.out.println(restApi.getWsapiVersion()); //v.2.0 by default when using 2.0.2 jar and up



                QueryRequest  releaseRequest = new QueryRequest("Release");
                releaseRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("Name"));
                releaseRequest.setLimit(1000);
                releaseRequest.setScopedDown(false);
                releaseRequest.setScopedUp(false);
               // releaseRequest.setWorkspace(workspaceRef);
                releaseRequest.setProject(projectRef);



                QueryResponse releaseQueryResponse = restApi.query(releaseRequest);
                int numberOfReleasesInProject = releaseQueryResponse.getTotalResultCount();
                System.out.println(numberOfReleasesInProject);

                if(numberOfReleasesInProject >0){
                    for (int i=0;i<numberOfReleasesInProject;i++){
                        JsonObject releaseJsonObject = releaseQueryResponse.getResults().get(i).getAsJsonObject();
                        System.out.println(releaseJsonObject.get("Name"));
                    }
                }
        }
        finally{
            if (restApi != null) {
                restApi.close();
            }
        }

    }
}
```